# Copy nested dict in list to new dict

Tags: python

Nested dict in list looks like:

```
 lista = [{stuff1: {key1: value1, key2: value2}},
          {stuff2: {keya: valuea, keyb: valueb}}]
```

How would i go about copying element 0 out of that list so that it becomes a new dict on its own?  Is it as simple as: `dicta = {lista[0]}`.

The background here is that i use enumerate to display the stuff keys to the user asking him to select the one he wants to work with.  He then just enters the "number" that the enumerate index shows for the given key.  Since I start the enumerate at index=1, I subtract 1 from the number he enters and that gives me the element in the list that corresponds to the dict he needs.

My thought here is now that I know the dict the user wants, I can just move that specific element out of lista into a new dict in order for further manipulation. Perhaps Im overthinking it and there is another way to simply leave lista as is and still do what I want.

Comment: I didn't really understand your description, but have a look at `copy.deepcopy`.

Comment: Your example list is not valid python. Otherwise: `lista` probably should be a _list_ of "dicts", so your first element of the list would _already_ be a dict.

Comment: @ChristianKönig I've updated the post. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `copy`

```
dicta = list[0].copy()
```

Demo

```
>>> l
[{1: 'aaa'}, {2: 'b'}]
>>> a = l[0].copy()
>>> a[1] = 'xxx'
>>> a
{1: 'xxx'}
>>> l
[{1: 'aaa'}, {2: 'b'}]
>>>
```

Then the new dict is a dict of its-own; Modification of it wont effect the elements in the list

If you do `dicta = list[0]` then any modification of `dicta` modify the list; [as its a `shallow copy/reference copy`]

Comment: This worked great!  I had to update the post as I had typed in my dict incorrectly when I created the OP but your solution still works!

Comment: Since these are nested dicts, it might be safer to use `copy.deepcopy()`